# Is there a way to have some kind of installer built into a C # application itself?

Tags: c#, installation

Is there a way to have some kind of installer built into a C # application itself? So that the installer is as small as possible so that the rest of the app is downloaded in the app itself?

My goal is when I publish my C # app that the user has a normal installer that is as small as it can be. And the rest of the app is downloaded in the app itself.

Comment: have a look at clickonce

Comment: ClickOnce is great if you're working in a relatively "open" environment.  In a highly secure environment, it is problematic.

Comment: The answer to your question as it stands is "yes". Please adjust your question, because at the moment it is "too broad" to be a good format for the sort of Q&A SO maintains. Chiefly you're supposed to design how you want it to work, have a go at it and ask is for help when you get stuck. Questions of the form "is it possible? If so how" don't fit with that for similar reasons of "is it possible to write a hotel booking system in c#? If so, please do it for me" aren't suited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure. Most modern software comes with an in-app updater. What you can do is, ship your App with just the updater component. Call the updater on first start and tell the user that the update is required.

Best achieved by a pre-compiled binary that does not require external frameworks to run. (E.g. select .NET target version of the lowest Update/OS you want to support).

Comment: Can you give an example?  This is a fairly content-free answer.

Comment: It's a pretty content-free question as well. How you write your updater, how your app is built and what your environment looks like can vary drastically.

Comment: I just have a problem, how to update the app, do i need something like an update server?

Comment: @someplacee Yeah of course. But it can be pretty simple. You can use the website you deploy your app to. Example: create a txt file called version and write the current version in there. Make it accessible at a static path (mywebsite.com/version). Grab the contents via a http request from your updater. Deploy your app bundle as <version>.zip. Download the bundle via your updater from mywebsite.com/<version>.zip. Unzip at the install path. Done.

Comment: Could you please give me sample code? I'm not very familiar with C # and networking in particular.

Comment: @adroste then the question is too broad to be a good fit for stack overflow

Comment: @someplacee Please adjust your question.